# Loop example in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, loops, procedure

I am trying to insert values which are divisible by 3 in a table *div_table* with only column in it as below:

```
Delimiter &&
create procedure multThree()
Begin
set @var = 10;
generate_data: loop
    if @var % 3 = 0 then
       set @var = @var+1;
       insert into div_table values (@var);
            if @var = 100 then
                  leave generate_data;
             end if;
    end if;
 end loop generate_data;
End &&
```

Is this code snippet fine? When i try to execute this query, it is showing me Error:2013 Lost connection to MYSQL server during query.

Comment: 10 % 3 = 1, Your condition never satisfies. That's why loop never end. you have to write ELSE part to leave loop.

Comment: understood! but i have to stop it at 100. I am getting bit confused with sql loop. In my first condition i will check for reminder = 0, then i will insert data into tabe and will incrementt the var value. In else part, i will write leave statement, but where should i mention stopping condition?